# How to get the same thresholds values for both functions precision_recall_curve and roc_curve in sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, precision-recall

I need to make a table with the TPR and FPR values, as well as precision and recall. I am using the roc_curve and precision_recall_curve functions from sklearn.metrics package in python. My problem is that every function give me a different vector for the thresholds, and I need only one, to merge the values as columns in a single table. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think they should give you the same values, though, right? Otherwise you can always interpolate....

Answer (score 0):

The threshold values have two major differences.

1. The orders are different. `roc_curve` has thresholds in decreasing order, while `precision_recall_curve` has thresholds in increasing order.
2. The numbers are different. In `roc_curve`, `n_thresholds = len(np.unique(probas_pred))`, while in `precision_recall_curve` the number `n_thresholds = len(np.unique(probas_pred)) - 1`. In the latter, the smallest threshold value from `roc_curve` is not included. In the same time, the last precision and recall values are 1. and 0. respectively with no corresponding threshold. Therefore, the numbers of items for tpr, fpr, precision and recall are the same.

So, back to your question, how to make a table to include tpr, fpr, precision and recall with corresponding thresholds? Here are the steps:

1. Discard the last precision and recall values
2. Reverse the precision and recall values
3. Compute the precision and recall values corresponding to the lowest threshold value from the thresholds of `roc_curve`
4. Put all the values into the same table